# Recursion in Probability questions

Tags: probability, self-study

I don't quit understand the explanation for recursion here. Why is there firstly the need to have i on the numerator for the first underlined bit? Would it be because of combinatorics? So the second term would be $\left(\frac12\right)^2$ multiplied by $\binom21$?

I would also appreciate any explanation of the second underlined part.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For the first part, recall that for discrete random variable, the expectation is

$$E[N]=\sum_i \color{blue}i\cdot  Pr(N=i)$$

The probability that you need $i$ tosses is $Pr(N=i)=\frac1{2^i}$.

Hence $$E[N]=\sum_i \frac{\color{blue}i}{2^i}.$$

For the second method, let $N$ be the number of flips until you see a head.

\begin{align}&E[N]\\&=1+E[N-1]
\\&=1+Pr(\text{you have gotten a head})\cdot E[(N-1)|\text{ you have gotten a flip]}\\&+Pr(\text{you haven't gotten a head})\cdot E[(N-1)|\text{ you haven't gotten a flip]}\\
&= 1+\frac12E[(N-1)|N=1)+\frac12E[(N-1)|N>1)\\
&= 1+\frac12 \cdot 0 + \frac12 E[N]\end{align}

If you have gotten a head, you do not need any more tosses. If you haven't gotten a head, the new tosses are independent from the previous toss, it is as if the process start over.